# how to blur component from interceptor

Tags: vue.js

user accesses page A. before It goes to that page, I have interceptor. let's say in an interceptor, I have got 401 status code.  when I have 401 status code, how can I blur(make the page A invisible) page A from that interceptor? I know what I can do is write the logic in Page A's component, but this way I'd have to write the same logic in every component. I prefer to blur components from interceptor. Is it possible?

Comment: It is unclear to me what exactly you are asking. Perhaps you can add some code that illustrates what you are trying to do, and tell us based on that what is not working as you would want.

Answer (score 0):

If you could add some code that would be helpful.

My first thought is that you could create a directive or a mixin, to accomplish this on your different page components, keeping the code in one place. But I could be off with that, I'd be happy to help if you could provide an example.